# How to generate fake real time data continously for mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, grafana, test-data

I actually need to visualise real-time data in grafana in MySQL. I initially used a seed_python file to generate random numbers, but now I want to have continuous values in MySQL

Here is the python code I used initially

```py
POSSIBLE_STATES = ['ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE']

class MySqlSeeder:

    def __init__(self):
        config = {
            'user': 'root',
            'password': 'something',
            'host': '192.168.99.100' if script_runs_within_container() else 'localhost',
            'port': '3306',
            'database': 'team'
        }
        while not hasattr(self, 'connection'):
            try:
                self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
                self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            except InterfaceError:
                print("MySQL Container has not started yet. Sleep and retry...")
                time.sleep(1)

    def seed(self):
        print("Clearing old data...")
        self.drop_user_table()
        print("Start seeding...")
        self.create_user_table()
        self.insert_users()

        self.connection.commit()
        self.cursor.close()
        self.connection.close()
        print("Done")

    def create_user_table(self):
        sql = '''
        CREATE TABLE users(
          id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
          number INT
        );
        '''
        self.cursor.execute(sql)

    def insert_users(self):
        for _ in range(300):
            sql = '''
            INSERT INTO users (number)
            VALUES (%(number)s);
            '''
            user_data = {
                'number': random.randint(1,100)
            }
            self.cursor.execute(sql, user_data)

    def drop_user_table(self):
        self.cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;')


    def script_runs_within_container():
        with open('/proc/1/cgroup', 'r') as cgroup_file:
            return 'docker' in cgroup_file.read()
    
    
    MySqlSeeder().seed()
```

Below is the docker-compose file

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: something
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql_seeding:
    build: ./DockerFiles
    depends_on:
      - mysql

volumes:
  grafana-storage:
  db_data:
```

**What could be the best way to perform continuous real-time data generation?**

Comment: Provide an example of data which you want to be generated. And specify **precise** mysql version.

Comment: I am lost. You say you need "real time data" but you paste a class manipulating users. Where is the data you mention? What is the problem? What is the aim?

Comment: @Maciek Actually Everytime I run the docker-compose, it generates a data of numbers(300 numbers). What I want is to have a data generator such that it may continuously add data to my database in real time so that I can visualise it in grafana.

Comment: @Akina mysql version used is 8.0.21 and data I need are random numbers only

Comment: *data I need are random numbers only* 1) What is the range this data must be between? 2) How many numbers do you need? 3) Does these numbers must be unique within the datatset? 4) How often do you need to generate such number set? does it may be dynamic or the numbers must be placed into some table?

Comment: I disagree with the decision to close this question for lack of specificity. With respect to the ones who closed it, sometimes less experienced devs don't know exactly how to describe their problems. If we closed all questions like that, SO would be expertsexchange. Please reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want a table containing random data generated every so often.  Here's such a table. Each row has an id, a timestamp called ts, and two float values va1, val2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE realtime (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    val1 FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
    val2 FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX time_vals (ts, val1, val2)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then, you need a way to insert a new row into that table every so often. That's done with a [MySQL EVENT object](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html).   Here's an example that puts data into that `realtime` table I just defined ten times a minute (every six seconds).

It also DELETEs rows older than a day, so your database won't get totally swamped with random useless garbage if you forget to DISABLE or DELETE the timer.
The index on `ts` speeds up the DELETE operation.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE EVENT `random_realtime`
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 6 SECOND 
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    ENABLE
    COMMENT 'Generating random timeseries test data. Please delete me in production.' 
DO BEGIN
    INSERT INTO realtime (val1, val2) VALUES  (RAND(), RAND());
    DELETE FROM realtime WHERE ts <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Finally, you need to tell MySQL to schedule your events. This command does that.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=ON;
```

You can put these three queries into the initialization of your Python program where you presently define your table.